# Factor of $2\pi$ inconstitency in fourier transform.

Tags: fourier-transform

Some fourier tranfsorm tables say that $\mathfrak{F}(1)=\delta$ and some say $\mathfrak{F}(1)=2\pi\delta$. I've always used $\mathfrak{F}(1)=2\pi\delta$ in earlier courses, but in current coursework I find that my answers differ by a factor $2\pi$ to the soultions. Is this only a consequence of different defintions?

Comment: There are just conflicting conventions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this only a consequence of different defintions?

Yes